# Background Color Showing Through As a Thin Border

Tags: html, css, border, outline

I have an issue where the black background color is showing through as a thin border in my HTML/CSS. The content is basically a div row with some

`background-color: white;`

divs inside. The black background color is set on

`.lip`.

I tried applying

`border: none; outline: none;`

but to no avail. I wasn't able to find a good answer online. Anyone know why this is happening? Here is the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pcwudrmc/55901/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that code

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

from

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked:). If you don't mind, do you know why that was causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that you can get some strange results using `backface-visibility: hidden;` so I thought I'd give it a try. Lo and beyond, I don't know why, but applying it to `.lip` got rid of the strange border.